# Different results for CUDA addition on host and on GPU

Tags: cuda

I have a function wich takes a color picture and returns the gray version of it.
If I run the sequential code on the host, everything works perfectly. If I run it on the device, the result is slightly different (one pixel in 1000 is either +1 or -1 compared to the correct value).

I think this has something to do with the conversions, but I don't know for sure. This is the code I use:

```
    __global__ void rgb2gray_d (unsigned char *deviceImage, unsigned char *deviceResult, const int height, const int width){
    /* calculate the global thread id*/
    int threadsPerBlock  = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;
    int threadNumInBlock = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.y;
    int blockNumInGrid   = blockIdx.x  + gridDim.x  * blockIdx.y;

    int globalThreadNum = blockNumInGrid * threadsPerBlock + threadNumInBlock;
    int i = globalThreadNum;

    float grayPix = 0.0f;
    float r = static_cast< float >(deviceImage[i]);
    float g = static_cast< float >(deviceImage[(width * height) + i]);
    float b = static_cast< float >(deviceImage[(2 * width * height) + i]);
    grayPix = (0.3f * r) + (0.59f * g) + (0.11f * b);

    deviceResult[i] = static_cast< unsigned char > (grayPix);
}

void rgb2gray(unsigned char *inputImage, unsigned char *grayImage, const int width, const int height, NSTimer &timer) {

    unsigned char *deviceImage;
    unsigned char *deviceResult;

    int initialBytes = width * height * 3;  
    int endBytes =  width * height * sizeof(unsigned char);

    unsigned char grayImageSeq[endBytes];

    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceImage, initialBytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceResult, endBytes);
    cudaMemset(deviceResult, 0, endBytes);
    cudaMemset(deviceImage, 0, initialBytes);

    cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(deviceImage, inputImage, initialBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    

    // Convert the input image to grayscale 
    rgb2gray_d<<<width * height / 256, 256>>>(deviceImage, deviceResult, height, width);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(grayImage, deviceResult, endBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    ////// Sequential
    for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
             for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
                   float grayPix = 0.0f;
                   float r = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(y * width) + x]);
                   float g = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(width * height) + (y * width) + x]);
                   float b = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(2 * width * height) + (y * width) + x]);

                   grayPix = (0.3f * r) + (0.59f * g) + (0.11f * b);
                   grayImageSeq[(y * width) + x] = static_cast< unsigned char > (grayPix);
              }
        }

    //compare sequential and cuda and print pixels that are wrong
    for (int i = 0; i < endBytes; i++)
    {
        if (grayImage[i] != grayImageSeq[i])
        cout << i << "-" << static_cast< unsigned int >(grayImage[i]) <<
                 " should be " << static_cast< unsigned int >(grayImageSeq[i]) << endl;
        }

    cudaFree(deviceImage);
    cudaFree(deviceResult);
}
```

I mention that I allocate for the initial image width * height * 3 because the initial image is a CImg.

I work on a GeForce GTX 480.

Comment: What does "slightly different" mean?

Comment: It means that approximately one pixel in 1000 is either +1 or -1 compared to the expected value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. CUDA does automatically fused multiply-add in both single and double precision. Using the document below [1](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf), Section 4.4, I managed to fix it. Instead of doing

```
grayPix = (0.3f * r) + (0.59f * g) + (0.11f * b);
```

I am now doing

```
grayPix = __fadd_rn(__fadd_rn(__fmul_rn(0.3f, r),__fmul_rn(0.59f, g)), __fmul_rn(0.11f, b));
```

This disables the merging of multiplies and adds into fused multiply-adds instructions.

[Floating Point and IEEE 754 Compliance for NVIDIA GPUs](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf)

Comment: thank u very much for this answer, rn modifiers helped me to fix different CPU and GPU results

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math can produce slightly different results in device code versus host code.

There are multiple possibilities why this is the case. You have to consider that these two functions are compiled by two different compilers into two different binary programs running on two different floating point hardware implementations.

For example if the floating point calculations are executed in different order rounding errors can cause different results.

Also when running floating point calculations with the 32-bit (float) or 64-bit (double) floating point representations on a x86 architecture CPU the floating point math is done by the FPU unit that internally uses 80-bit precision and  the result is then truncated back to 32-bit for float data type or 64-bit for the double data type.

The ALUs of a GPU use 32-bit precision for floating point math (assuming you are using the float data type).

An excellent article discussing the topic of floating point representations and arithmetics can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was wondering what should be the best way to avoid this in my code? I tried almost everything! :) Thnx

Comment: @andreea.sandu what exactly do you want to avoid? do you demand that the two results must be absolutely equal? I also have to note that direct comparison of two floating point numbers like your grayImage[i] != grayImageSeq[i] is considered a bad practice and should be avoided unless you are sure that exact comparison is really what you want. Look at this for some ideas of how to do this properly: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: @andreea.sandu in image processing something tiny like this shouldn't matter. If you really really need "correct" results, use double precision for temporary values (both on cpu and gpu).

Comment: Actually after this step I calculate a histogram, so I count the number of pixels of each value. This is why I need the numbers to be exactly the same.

Comment: Expecting the answer to be exact is not really correct. You will likely get the same issue if you compare x86 FPU to SSE generate answer. There are several things you could try. (1) disable FMAs on GPU. (2) Generate 3 256 entry look up tables on CPU side and replace your multiplies with lookups (~8 way divergence on each lookup). (3) Generate a 2^24 entry lookup table on the host and use it on the CPU.

Comment: I agree with Greg, unless you manage to use the same precision, ensure the use of the same floating point standard and the same sequence of operations, you can not expect to always get results that are exactly the same.

Comment: I am wondering why you even bother with CUDA in this case. Unless the input data originates in the GPU and the result is used by some other function on the GPU it is unlikely that you will be much faster on the GPU than on the CPU. The computation time is going to be dominated by the transfers between the host and the GPU memory. Even if you would ignore the transfer times, your kernel does only 3 floating point instructions for which you need to transfer 4 bytes of data so you are going to by limited by the memory bandwidth anyway.

Comment: I am also wondering why you use floating point numbers at all... your histogram can by calculated with integer math, and the results are guaranteed to be the same between the GPU and CPU. You can use integer variables or even int16. Calculate it like this: grayPix = ((30 * r) + (59 * g) + (11 * b) + 50)/100;

Comment: The most likely cause of the differences is that that "grayPix" computation is carried out with higher than single precision on the host. To prevent this, declare some "volatile float" variables in your host code, and then decompose the entire computation into a sequence of individual operations with two inputs, with each operations's result going to a volatile float destination. E.g.: { volatile float t0,t1,t2; t0=0.3f*r; t1=0.59f*g; t2=0.11f*b; t0=t0+t1; t0=t0+t2; grayPix=t0; } I use this technique all the time when I design code intended for the GPU on my host system. Works like a charm.