# Differences in rounding on GPU and CPU

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to implement a CUDA version of an algorithm to convert an image to grayscale. I've got it working, but I'm having troubles with a few of the pixels. I discovered that one of the rounding operations I'm doing on the GPU has a slightly different outcome than if I were to run it on my CPU. I'm wondering if there is any way to make my GPU behave in exactly the same way as my CPU. I've tried some nvcc compile flags (fzt=false/true and prec-div=false/true) but to no avail. I've also tried doing all my operations on doubles, as they are supposed to be more precise, but that didn't help either. 
Here's my CUDA kernel, and the equivalent sequential version:

CUDA

```
_global__ void darkenImage(const unsigned char * inputImage,
    unsigned char * outputImage, const int width, const int height, int iteration){

  int x = ((blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + (iteration * MAX_BLOCKS * nrThreads)))%width;
  int y = ((blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + (iteration * MAX_BLOCKS * nrThreads)))/width;

  if(x < width && y < height){
    float grayPix = 0.0f;
    float r = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(y * width) + x]);
    float g = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(width * height) + (y * width) + x]);
    float b = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(2 * width * height) + (y * width) + x]);

    grayPix = fma(0.3f,r,fma(0.59f,g,(0.11f * b)));
    grayPix = fma(grayPix,0.6f,0.5f);


    outputImage[(y * width) + x] = static_cast< unsigned char >(grayPix);
  }
}
```

Sequential

```
for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
      float grayPix = 0.0f;
      float r = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(y * width) + x]);
      float g = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(width * height) + (y * width) + x]);
      float b = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(2 * width * height) + (y * width) + x]);

      grayPix = ((0.3f * r) + (0.59f * g) + (0.11f * b));
      grayPix = (grayPix * 0.6f) + 0.5f;

      outputImage2[(y * width) + x] = static_cast< unsigned char >(grayPix);
    }
  }
```

All my runs are done on either a Nvidia GTX 560-Ti or a GTX 480, both should have compute capability 2.0.

Regards,
Linus

Comment: Okay, I'm really sorry. I just saw that someone had asked the EXACT same question, and had found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406364/different-results-for-cuda-addition-on-host-and-on-gpu?rq=1 Sorry if I wasted anyones time!

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. (But a good question properly asked anyway :) )